# A graph such that every set $S$ of vertices has at least $\frac32|S|$ neighbors, then $(\frac32)^{\frac{\text{diameter}-4}{2}}\leq n$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and with diameter $k$. Let $N(S)=\cup_{s \in S} N(s)$ denote the set of neighbors of $S \subseteq V$.

Suppose that every set $S\subset V$ of size at most $\frac n2$ satisfies $|N(S)| \geq \frac32|S|$.

> Prove that $(\frac32)^{\frac{k-4}{2}}\leq n$.

**What I have so far:**

We first note that $G$ is *connected*, because otherwise we choose the smallest connected component $U$ of $G$ and apply the assumption to conclude that $|N(U)| \geq 1.5 |U| > |U|$, but $N(U) \subseteq U$ so this is a contradiction.

Let $v$ be a vertex that realizes the diameter. I got an advice to look at the sequence defined by $a_0=1, a_1=|N(v)|, a_2=|N(N(v))|\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}N^2(v)$ and so on, $a_m=|N^m(v)|$.

We have $a_m \geq (\frac32)^m$ as long as $a_1,...,a_{m-1} $ are all $\leq \frac n2$. This is equivalent to requiring only $a_{m-1} \leq \frac n2$, because whenever the sequence exceeds $\frac n2$ it will never go below $\frac 34 n >\frac n2$, since we can always take a subset $U'$ of size $\frac n2$ out of a set $U$ of size $\geq \frac n2$, and $N(U) \supseteq N(U')$.

We also have $a_m \leq n$ for all $m$. So if we prove that $a_{\frac{k-2}{4}-1} \leq \frac n2$ then we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something slightly stronger should be true.

Let $u,v$ be a pair of vertices realising the diameter, so $d(u,v) = k$.

Let $X_i$ be the set of vertices at distance at most $i$ from the vertex $u$, and let $Y_j$ be the set of vertices at distance at most $j$ from the vertex $v$.  Let $a$ be the largest index such that $|X_a| \le \frac{n}{2}$, and let $b$ be the largest index such that $|Y_b| \le \frac{n}{2}$.

As you noted, since $X_i = N(X_{i-1}) = ... = N^i(u)$, we must have $|X_a| \ge \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^a$, and similarly $|Y_b| \ge \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^b$.

Now we claim that $a + b \ge k - 2$.  Indeed, by definition $|X_{a+1}|, |Y_{b+1}| > \frac{n}{2}$.  Hence they cannot be disjoint, and so there must be some vertex $w$ that is distance $a+1$ from $u$ and distance $b+1$ from $v$.  This gives a walk of length $a + b + 2$ between $u$ and $v$.  However, since $d(u,v) = k$, we have $a + b + 2 \ge k$.

Without loss of generality, suppose $a = \max \{a,b\} \ge \frac{a+b}{2} \ge \frac{k-2}{2}$.  We then have $\frac{n}{2} \ge |X_a| \ge \left( \frac32 \right)^a \ge \left( \frac32 \right)^{\frac{k-2}{2}}$, and so $n \ge 2 \left( \frac32 \right)^{\frac{k-2}{2}}.$